# Pandas print Series elements as "repr" not "str"

Tags: python, pandas

When you `print` a `Series` with with dtype `object` or `string`, the elements are printed as if you called `str()`.

For example, `print(pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c']))` yields:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

Is it possible to tell Pandas to use `repr()` and not `str()` to render elements for printing? The desired output in the example above would be:

```
0    'a'
1    'b'
2    'c'
dtype: object
```

As a workaround, you can call `my_series.apply(repr)`, but it would be nice if I could set this as some kind of Pandas option more generally. I looked in the list of Pandas options in the docs and didn't see anything like this.

Comment: There are a few options for specific formatting (e.g. floats) but nothing of the kind. Might be worth a feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not currently seem possible in Pandas. I have made a feature request here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46744 but this might be considered too niche to be worth adding to Pandas.

The best workaround is to use `DataFrame.to_string`, with `repr` as the formatter for every string/object column.