# How to insert a tab in a Pandas cell?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tabs, cell

When I try to insert the string 'ABC\tDEF' in a Pandas cell the escaped tab is not inserted. When the cell is printed I get "ABC\tDEF" instead of the expected "ABC      DEF".

I tried using f-strings and specifying the tab as a unicode character. I also noticed that the same situation applies to new line characters.

What am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832297/pandas-print-series-elements-as-repr-not-str . Short answer, pandas doesn't support printing strings when you print the whole dataframe. If you do `print(df.loc[key]['col'])` you will see the tab, but you can't make it display everything like that with `print(df)`.

Comment: Thank you - I would never have figured that out.